# How to compare multiple QStrings at once?

Tags: c++, qt

In **qt** there's another way to compare multiple strings than writing many `str1 == str2 || ...`

```cpp
QString a = "red";
QString b = "yellow";
QString c = "blue";
QString d = "green";
QString e = "gray";

if (a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e)
{
}
```

Comment: Which container? QList? an example?

Comment: Put the strings in a QStrringList and use [QStringList::contains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringlist.html#contains)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple approach is to create a container with all of allowable strings and use its `find` function to see if it's in the container. Depending on the container you select it may not have it's own find function. In that case you can still rely on `std::find` to simply find the string.

The following example uses a `std::set` to store all the valid strings you want to find and uses its `find` member function to handle the searching without doing any additional checks for strings you may want to ignore.

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::set<QString> validLabels{ "yellow", "blue", "green", "gray" };
    std::vector<QString> needles{ "red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "gray" };
    for (const auto& needle : needles)
    {
        if (validLabels.find(needle) != validLabels.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Found " << needle << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Did not find " << needle << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The following example uses a `std::vector` to store all allowable strings and uses `std::find` to find the string.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::vector<QString> validLabels{ "yellow", "blue", "green", "gray" };
    std::vector<QString> needles{ "red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "gray" };
    for (const auto& needle : needles)
    {
        if (std::find(validLabels.begin(), validLabels.end(), needle) != validLabels.end())
        {
            std::cout << "Found " << needle << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Did not find " << needle << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Both examples generate the following output

```
Did not find red
Found yellow
Found blue
Found green
Found gray
```